# Unable to read property value in extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, extension-methods

I have read in SO that

> Class Extensions were also specifically designed to allow a property to publicly `readonly` and privately `readwrite`.

So I made a clas `abc` having following code:

```
 @interface abc ()

 @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *sampleString;

 @end

 @implementation abc


  @end
```

I want to acceess `sampleString` in another class subclass of `abc`

I made a class `pqr` subclass of `abc`

in `pqr` i am trying to access `sampleStr` but not able to do this.

```
 @implementation cccc

  - (void)accessPrivateMember
 {
   self.sampleStr ; //Not able to acces

 } 

 @end
```

Is my direction is wrong ?

Comment: Because `sampleString` is not in the public interface of the class. Declare this property in the `.h` file of your class.

Comment: Add readonly property in abc.h as @property (strong,nonatomic, readonly) NSString *sampleString;

Answer (score 0):

You should put property in header file (.h). In your case `sampleString` is private property because it is in implementation file(.m). Also, if you want access private property you can use `self.valueForKey("sampleStr")`

Answer (score 0):

You should make this property public in abc's '.h' file. Add this:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *sampleString;
```